# How call function before route change and when function done change route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i wonder how call some function when click to:

```
<Link to="/">page</Link>
```

and call some function before before route change.

eg

I'm in component A i'm click some link for going Component B. Route will change but before route change i wan't to play some javascript animation and wan't to wait animation will finish then route will go to component B.

I'm using react-router-4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<Link />` you can change route programmatically:

```
<Button
  onClick={
  () => {
      this.myCustomFunction(); // Execute whatever code you need
      this.props.history.push('/');
     }
  }
></Button>
```

Ref: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a carousel transition effect before by routing all my paths to the same carousel component and in the carousel, each slide represented a page. When the location path changed the carousel component would check the path and slide into the next component. A similar idea could be used for any transition.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route exact path='/history' component={Home} />
    <Redirect to="/" />
</Switch>
```

```
public render() {
    let locationPath = this.state.locationPath.toLowerCase();

    return (
        <div style={{ height: "100%" }} id="pageCarousel" className="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval={false} >
            <div style={{ height: "100%" }} className="carousel-inner" >
                <div className={"carousel-item summary" + (locationPath == "/" ? " active" : "")}>
                    <div className="overlay" />
                    <div className="pageContainer">
                        <Summary />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className={"carousel-item history" + (locationPath == "/history" ? " active" : "")}>
                    <div className="overlay" />
                    <div className="pageContainer">
                        <History />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What if the route brings to a different component ? This may **not work** for the OP purpose. It states " **from Component A to Component B** "

Comment: @AntonioBuelli That what the `Carousel` (in the above example, called `Home`) component handles. Basically, the page routes are `<Summary />` and `<History />` but instead of setting your route component like `<Route exact path='/history' component={History } />` you would set it to `<Route exact path='/history' component={Carousel} />` and in the `Carousel` component, if the path location is '/history', transition and display the `History` component (`<History />`)

Comment: It just works but is a hack that may need an expensive refactor while the OP could simply "do something, then change route" as described in other answers.

Comment: That depends on if they want to transition into the new route. If they "do something" then go to a new route, that's only a transition out, not a transition in. If they add a transition in on the new component, there will be blank or unrelated filler content between the transition. Also, the transition would display even if they came directly to the page and not through application routing. And, if they wanted to transition every page they would need to add the transition out and transition in to every route, whereas this method handles all the transitions in one component.

Comment: Op talks about "animation" not "transition"

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by calling an function when the link is clicked

```
<Button
  onClick={
  () => {
      this.animateAndExit()
     }
  }
></Button>
```

and your function will be like this

```
const animateAndExit = () => {
animationFunction()
setTimeout(redirectionFunction, timeToWait)
}
```